# How to set up DOJO

Tags: dojo

I am a beginer to DOJO , finding difficulty to set up DOJO

This is my Program :

```
<html>

<head>

<script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</script>

<title>button</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  dojo.require("dojo.event.*");
  dojo.require("dojo.widget.*");
  dojo.require("dojo.widget.Button");



  function init()
  {
    alert('Click on the Hello World Button');
  }

  dojo.addOnLoad(init);
  </script>


</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFCC">


</body>

</html>
```

I have used the dojo.js file from the external site itself that is by

```
**<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>**
```

But still i am getting errors .
Please see the screen shot related to errors

```
http://imageshack.us/f/545/dojoh.jpg/
```

Also i have downloaded , the DOJO Latest  relaese , and kept this in C:\dojo-release-1.6.1

Could anybody kindly  please tell me , **as what should be the source path to dojo js , i tried the below way** , but doesn't know why this js file hasn't been recognized

Thank you for your time .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track, there's just a small issue with your HTML. The following snippet is not valid:

```
<script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</script>
```

You can't have a `<script>` tag within another `<script>` tag. Remove the outer tags, so you're left with just this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is what caused the "unexpected end of XML source" error. Also, since the error prevents dojo from being loaded, you get the "dojo is not defined" right afterwards.

Secondly, you cannot require dojo modules with wildcards ('*'). You have to explicitly require the ones you want to use. So the following is not valid:

```
dojo.require("dojo.event.*");
dojo.require("dojo.widget.*");
```

Lastly, you probably want to run your Dojo application through a web server, not just as a local file. It may work for now, but you're bound to run into some weird issues after a while.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML code you have here Dojo won't load, as script tag loading dojo is inside another script tag. Get rid off the outside script tag.

You should only require modules that you need. Here you do not seem to need any of the extra dojo modules. 
Here is an example of having dijit.form.Button http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/form/Button.html It will give you better idea of how you can load modules.

To load dojo.js file from your computer, if your HTML file is in projects dir then you may add your dojo-release-1.6.1 dir inside projects dir and may want to rename it as libs. Then in your HTML file you should load dojo.js file as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much  Frode and Percy .

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, please note that your sample code reflects Dojo 0.4 APIs from about 5 years ago.  The code has been refactored significantly since then.  Most widgets live in the `dijit` package